# Como lidar com múltiplas aspas no R?

Tags: r, postgresql, query

Meu problema está em usar as aspas em um query dentro de uma função do R.

Tenho que chamar uma lista de

```
select * from probes."probes_90_2018-05"
```

Para tanto faço:

```
coelho<-dbConnect("PostgreSQL", fnord)
dbGetQuery(coelho,"select *
from probes."probes_97_2018-06"")
dbDisconnect(coelho)
```

Então o meu problema começa, pois o R passa a achar que `probes_97_2018-06` é uma variável. Já tente utilizar `\"` e `/"`, mas não tive sucesso. Então como é o escape do R?

Continuando: no formado

```
dbGetQuery(coelho,'select * from probes."probes_97_2018-06" LIMIT 2')
```

funcionou, entretanto fiquei curiosa para saber o porquê que assim fucina e mais quando faço:

```
> 'select * from probes."probes_97_2018-06" LIMIT 2'
```

retorna

```
[1] "select * from probes.\"probes_97_2018-06\" LIMIT 2"
```

Comment: E as aspas simples dentro das aspas duplas funciona? tipo dbGetQuery(coelho,"select *
from probes.'probes_97_2018-06' ")

Comment: Já tentou as *back quotes*? (Desculpe o inglês.)

Comment: Obrigado!!! No formato ```dbGetQuery(coelho,"select * from probes.'probes_97_2018-06' LIMIT 2")``` não funciona,  mas no formado ```dbGetQuery(coelho,'select * from probes."probes_97_2018-06" LIMIT 2')``` funcionou.

Comment: Agora fiquei curiosa para saber o porque que assim fucina e mais quando faço: ```> 'select * from probes."probes_97_2018-06" LIMIT 2'``` retorna ```[1] "select * from probes.\"probes_97_2018-06\" LIMIT 2"```

Comment: Se vc fizer assim deve funcionar também, usando o back-slash na single quote. ` dbGetQuery(coelho,"select * from probes.\'probes_97_2018-06\' ")  `  Mas repare que pela documentação parece que exite um concatenação de Aspas que deve ser seguida a partir da primeira Aspas! Seguem referências retiradas da documentação. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html

Comment: No PostgreSQL as aspas(") tem um significado especial: elas indicam um identificador delimitado ou quoted identifier. É formado colocando-se uma sequência arbitrária de caracteres entre aspas e é interpretado como um identificado e não como uma string. Veja Identifiers and Key Words em https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em uma frase: para usar múltiplas aspas no `R`, escapes as aspas do texto ou envolva o texto em aspas diferentes das aspas usadas no texto.

### Em maiores detalhes

O [r](/questions/tagged/r) não diferencia aspas duplas ou simples para designar vetor de classe `character`.

```
"Um texto" # duplas
# [1] "Um texto"
'Um texto' # simples
# [1] "Um texto"
```

A coisa muda de figura, no entanto, dentro da `string`. Neste caso, o `R` busca preservar a informação passada (conforme  demonstra a própria pergunta).

```
'select * from probes."probes_97_2018-06" LIMIT 2'
# [1] "select * from probes.\"probes_97_2018-06\" LIMIT 2"
```

O mesmo resultado pode ser obtido com aspas duplas, mas para isso precisamos escapar as aspas que vão dentro da `string`. Caso contrário, o `R` acharia que estamos terminando a string e esperaria encontrar um código interpretável na parte que segue (`probes_97_2018-06`).

```
# sem escapar as aspas
"select * from probes."probes_97_2018-06" LIMIT 2"
# Erro: unexpected symbol in ""select * from probes."probes_97_2018"
```

Isso pode ser evitado escapando as aspas

```
# aspas de dentro escapadas
"select * from probes.\"probes_97_2018-06\" LIMIT 2"
# [1] "select * from probes.\"probes_97_2018-06\" LIMIT 2"
```

A igualdade entre os dois tipos de aspas externas pode ser observado com

```
"aspas" == 'aspas'
# [1] TRUE
```

Por fim, podemos ter todos os tipos de aspas dentro de uma `string`.

```
"string em aspas duplas com aspas \"duplas\" e 'simples'"
# [1] "string em aspas duplas com aspas \"duplas\" e 'simples'"
'string em aspas simples com aspas "duplas" e \'simples\''
# [1] "string em aspas simples com aspas \"duplas\" e 'simples'"
```

Comment: Infelizmente, não poderei testar a resposta.